# Connection Refused Error at Run ReactNative Project

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I create new react-native project with command:

```
react-native init myProject
```

But When I want run it on emulator or real device with this command:

```
react-native run-android
```

I got this error and app not build:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
fresco/1.10.0/fresco-1.10.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/fresco
/1.10.0/fresco-1.10.0.pom'.
            > Connect to 127.0.0.1:9595 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused:
 connect
```

In build.gradle I added google() but did not solve problem.
This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Anybody help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found answer.
I open android folder of project in Android Studio and try to sync project with proxy and related dependency downloaded. Then I run this command and project build successfully.

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I solve it by using proxy