# Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, environment-variables, genymotion

I recently started to use react native, but according to Iranians Sanctions, gradle cannot build my first projects, so I used VPN and also [shecan service](https://shecan.ir/) but I get the following error:

[image: my error]

I read React native instructions and followed them, set up an emulator, react native cli, and chocolaty service. In environments, it was written that I should define my platform-tools folder of my SDK in a variable named `PATH`. But in variables, I have already had path in username and in system variables. In edit, I have added my platform-tools to them. But unfortunately it didn't work yet.

[image: my enviroments]

The PowerShell error messages in the image are:

```
PS C:\Others\RN_projects\React_native_shop\shop_project> react-native run-android
```

> Starting JS server...
>
> Building and installing the app on the device (cd android &&
>   gradlew.bat installDebug)... FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'shop_project'. Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration
>     ':classpath'. Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
>
> Required by:
>
> project : Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
>   Could not get resource
>   'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET
>   'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>   Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused:
>   connect
>
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
>
> Could not get resource
>   'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET
>   'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>
> Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused:
>   connect
>
> - Try:
>
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>   or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
>   insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 3s Could not install the app on the device, read the
>   error above for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator
>   running or a device connected and have set up your Android development
>   environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
>
> events.js:173
>
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
>
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:246:19) at onErrorNT
>   (internal/child_process.js:421:16) at processTicksAndRejections
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
>
> Emitted 'error' event at: at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:252:12) at onErrorNT
>   (internal/child_process.js:421:16) at processTicksAndRejections
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)

Answer (score 4):

Add this proxy information to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=9595
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=9595
```

and set above proxy port (ex. 9595) in your vpn like psiphon.
Then sync project.

[see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53853433/8770663)

Comment: thank you but it dosent work yet :(
i changed the gradle version but it cant find the  gradle-3.2.1.pom or other versions !
when i open the URL in browser , eror is :

  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Could not find resource"
 

but it should work :|

Comment: do you used vpn?

Comment: yess , I tested teh-vpn , x-vpn , hotspot-shild and pisphone , and with all of them I set proxy and port in gradle.properties .
i think it looks like the problem is about gradle version or sth like that . what gradle version do you use or whith sdk-target for build do you offer ? 
Its about a week im trying but nothing :(

Comment: please use psiphone and set proxy port in psiphone too. In psiphone at settings->local proxy ports->at field HTTP/HTTPS set your port (for example 9595). then sync projec.

Comment: please send email to me: masoud.mokhtari69@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.
What I tried:

- changed the gradle version, changed the gradle plugin version
- changed repositories where packages are searched
- set proxy settings in gradle.properties file
- set proxy settings in Windows 10 network settings

None of this helped me, and I installed a proxy program that can wrap the traffic of individual applications on the computer, and it worked!
It was a Proxyfire program - it has a 30-day free version.
The problem of accessing Google services in my case is related to local restrictions.