# Android Studio:Gradle project sync failed. basic functionality will not work properly

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have use the VPN and `try it again` but still not working.
If I direct access the website, it's ok. Please see stacktrace at below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your Android Studio in offline mode?

Comment: Did you test that your VPN is correctly configured for Android Studio to use?

Comment: Can you try this one. Not exactly the same issue but just a hunch :) https://discuss.gradle.org/t/android-studio-could-not-get-resource-https-dl-google-com-dl-android-maven2-com-android-tools-build-gradle-3-1-0-gradle-3-1-0-pom/26734/7

Comment: How to check if it is offline mode?Yes.Http_proxy and https_proxy is both 127.0.0.1:1081.I also try to use tun2socks to forward all the traffic.But it is not working.

Comment: I have try that one,But not working.Thank you Raghavendra

Comment: Do not add screenshots of code or errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this proxy information to your gradle.properties file:

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=9595
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=9595
```

and set above proxy port (ex. 9595) in your vpn like psiphone. Then sync project.

And add `mavenCentral()` to your `build.gradle` of project like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name 'Sonatype SNAPSHOTs'
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()

        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54723267/8770663).

Comment: It works!Thank you.I originally set the http and https to the socks proxy.

Comment: Good luck bro:)